# Problem regular express pattern hunting similar matches

Tags: php, regex

I have one of the four patter:

```
"Test"
'Test'
`Test`
(Test)
```

Is it possible to get "Test" with a single `preg_match` call?

I tried the following:

```
if ( preg_match( '/^(?:"(.*)"|\'(.*)\'|`(.*)`|\((.*)\')$/iu', $pattern, $matches ) )
```

... but this gives me five elements of `$matches` back. But I would like to have two only (One for the whole match and one for the found match with "Test" in it.)

Comment: What do you mean by one with the whole match?

Comment: Each time that you write a couple of parenthesis the regex engine will allocate memory for the group even if it will be empty at when matching.

Comment: What should be the result for `"test'` or `'test)` or `"('test)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use dot to match the characters aroun d the word and use array_unique to remove duplicates.

```
preg_match_all("/.(\w+)./", $str,$match);
foreach($match as &$m) $m = array_unique($m);

var_dump($match);
```

https://3v4l.org/T2hnh

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    string(6) ""Test""
    [1]=>
    string(6) "'Test'"
    [2]=>
    string(6) "`Test`"
    [3]=>
    string(6) "(Test)"
  }
  [1]=>
  &array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(4) "Test"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To make sure that the single quote, back tick and double quote and have the same closing char you might use a capturing group with a [backreference](https://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html) to that group.

To get the same group in the alternation to also match `(` with the closing `)` you might use a [branch reset group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/branchreset.html).

The match  for `Test` is in group 2

```
(?|(["'`])(Test)\1|\(((Test)\)))
```

**Explanation**

- `(?|` Branch reset group

  - `` (["'`]) `` Capture in group 1 any of the listed
  - `(Test)\1` Capture in group 2 matching Test followed by a backreference  `\1` to group 1
  - `|` Or
  - `\(((Test)\))` Match `(`, capture in group 2 matching `Test` followed by `)`
- `)` Close branch reset group

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sVH0bw/1) | [Php demo](https://3v4l.org/OUQAH)

For example:

```
$strings = [
    "\"Test\"",
    "'Test'",
    "`Test`",
    "(Test)",
    "Test\"",
    "'Test",
    "Test`",
    "(Test",
    "\"Test'",
    "'Test\"",
    "`Test",
    "Test)",
];
$pattern = '/(?|(["\'`])(Test)\1|\(((Test)\)))/';
foreach ($strings as $string){
    $isMatch = preg_match($pattern, $string, $matches);
    if ($isMatch) {
        echo "Match $string ==> " . $matches[2] . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

Result

```
Match "Test" ==> Test
Match 'Test' ==> Test
Match `Test` ==> Test
Match (Test) ==> Test
```

Comment: Nice use of the branch reset group that's effective

Answer (score 0):

You can use non-capturing groups :

```
 '/^(?:"|\'|`|\()(.*)(?:"|\'|`|\))$/iu'
```

So just the (.*) group will capture data.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex could be:

```
^['"`(](.+)['"`)]$
```

Which would give off the following code in PHP:

```php
if(preg_match('^[\'"`(](.+)[\'"`)]$', $pattern, $matches))
```

### Explanation

In Regex, character groups—marked with enclosing square brackets `[]`— matches one of the characters inside of it.

Comment: Take care of escaping characters this code won't run

Comment: @Abel yep forgot that, fixed it.